# I am trying to make image appear onclick, and the script is not executing

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, display

I'm trying to make a separate image appear when you click an active image on a page.

I've tried moving the onclick into the `<a>` tag, the `<img>` tag, the `<div>` tag, I've tried using different versions of this script command, nothing will seem to make it work. The active images and the cursor:pointer all work, but the java is failing. Any ideas??

```js
function opencontact() {
  var x = document.getElementById("instagram");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "inline";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.insta {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 180px;
  right: 220px;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0s;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lips2" class="lipbtn2">
  <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="opencontact()">
<a>
<img src="https://www.country935.ca/wp-content/uploads/sites/19/2017/07/a-kiss.jpg" width="15%" height="auto" alt="" class="kiss2">
<img src="https://dzasv7x7a867v.cloudfront.net/product_photos/34277616/20150910_011229_1000w.png" width="15%" height="auto" alt="" class="kiss2active">
</a>
</span>
</div>

<div id="instagram" class="insta">
  <a href="http://instagram.com/"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Instagram_logo_2016.svg/1200px-Instagram_logo_2016.svg.png" alt="" width="124px" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't realize my markup would get hidden but i meant to write that I tried to move the onclick in to the div tag, the a tag, and the img tag, and all are not working.

Comment: What is the point of the `<a>` tag?

Comment: the ```<a>```  triggers a hover element where the active image (lips2active) replaces the first one (this function works fine) I also tried including the on click in that ```<a>``` tag but it didn't work

Comment: kiss2active** i mean not lips

Comment: I made you a snippet. It works but you have to click twice because your code does not see the "none" when running. I changed the height of the insta to make a [mcve]

Comment: in my opinion URL spaces characters are problematic, they must be replaced by `%20`

Comment: it's strange; for me now both snippets (my original and your fix) are working (and with only one click!) but when i'm trying it on the site html its still not happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the test around or you will have to click twice

I am not sure what else you want to happen

```js
function opencontact() {
  var x = document.getElementById("instagram");
  x.style.display = x.style.display === "inline"? "none" : "inline"
}
```

```css
.insta {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 180px;
  right: 220px;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0s;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lips2" class="lipbtn2">
  <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="opencontact()">
<a>
<img src="https://www.country935.ca/wp-content/uploads/sites/19/2017/07/a-kiss.jpg" width="15%" height="auto" alt="" class="kiss2">
<img src="https://dzasv7x7a867v.cloudfront.net/product_photos/34277616/20150910_011229_1000w.png" width="15%" height="auto" alt="" class="kiss2active">
</a>
</span>
</div>

<div id="instagram" class="insta">
  <a href="http://instagram.com/"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Instagram_logo_2016.svg/1200px-Instagram_logo_2016.svg.png" alt="" width="124px" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: OK for some reason i don't understand also it just started working. Anyway thanks for the quick help.